# How to call a subroutine with a variable pre-assigned to some value?

Tags: perl, scope

In Perl, when one uses the `sort` function with a custom comparison, the variables `$a` and `$b` are already assigned to the current pair of elements to compare, e.g. in:

```
@decreasing = sort { $b <=> $a } @list;
```

How can I write other subroutines with a similar functionality? For example, imagine that I want to write sort of `process_and_store` function that does something special with each item of a list and then stores it in a database; and where the variable `$item` is already assigned to the current item being processed. I would like to write for example something like:

```
process_and_store { do_something_with($item); } @list;
```

Rather than

```
process_and_store { my $item = shift; do_something_with($item); } @list;
```

How should I go about doing this?

---

**UPDATE:** For completeness, although [flesk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10413915/359178) works without problems, in order to “properly” localize the changes I make to the `$item` variable I had to follow the [advice from Axeman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414437/359178). In `SomePackage.pm` I placed something like:

```
package SomePackage;

use strict;

require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw/Exporter/;
our @EXPORT = qw(process_and_store);

our $item;

sub import { 
  my $import_caller = caller();
  {   no strict 'refs';
    *{ $import_caller . '::item' } = \*item;
  }
  # Now, cue Exporter!
  goto &{ Exporter->can( 'import' ) };
}

sub process_and_store (&@) {
  my $code = shift;
  for my $x (@_) {
    local *item = \$x;
    $code->();
    print "stored: $item\n"
  }
}

1;
```

Then I call this from `main.pl` with something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use SomePackage;

process_and_store { print "seen: $item\n"; } (1, 2, 3);
```

And get the expected result:

```
seen: 1
stored: 1
seen: 2
stored: 2
seen: 3
stored: 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my "associative array" processing library, I do something similar. The user can export the variables `$k` and `$v` (key-value) so that they can do things like this:

```
each_pair { "$k => $v" } some_source_list()
```

Here's how I do it:

1. I declare `our ( $k, $v )` in the implementing package.
2. In `import` I allow packages to export those symbols and alias them in the
   receiving package: `*{$import_caller.'::'.$name} = \*{ $name };`
3. In the pair processors, I do the following:

   ```
   local *::_ = \$_[0];
   local *k   = \$_[0];
   local *v   = \$_[1];
   @res = $block->( $_[0], $_[1] );
   ```

Thus `$k` and `$v` are *aliases* of what's in the queue. If this doesn't have to be the case, then you might be happy enough with something *like* the following:

```
local ( $k, $v ) = splice( @_, 0, 2 );
local $_         = $k;
```

But modifiable copies also allow me to do things like:

```
each_pair { substr( $k, 0, 1 ) eq '-' and $v++ } %some_hash;
```

---

**UPDATE:**

It seems that you're neglecting step #2. You have to make sure that the symbol in the client package maps to your symbol. It can be as simple as:

```
our $item;

sub import { 
    my $import_caller = caller();
    {   no strict 'refs';
        *{ $import_caller . '::item' } = \*item;
    }
    # Now, cue Exporter!
    goto &{ Exporter->can( 'import' ) };
}
```

Then when you localize your own symbol, the aliased symbol in the client package is localized as well.

The main way that I can see that it would work without the `local`, is if you were calling it from the same package. Otherwise, `$SomePackage::item` and `$ClientPackage::item` are two distinct things.

Comment: I've tried to follow some of your advise to "localize" the change of the variable name; but can't get it to work. I've updated my question with the details. Could you help?

Comment: Hmm.. I was expecting `our @EXPORT = qw(process_and_store $item);` to take care of that. In fact, if I add an `import` sub as you suggest (and remove `$item` from the list of exports), the `process_and_store` doesn't seem to be exported anymore.

Comment: @JuanAntonio - Yeah, I couldn't get Exporter to do that for me either. There's a trick. I'll update my post.

Comment: Amazing! Now it works as expected. I didn't imagine it would be that tricky, but I'm happy now that it works.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bit of a hack, but you could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $item;

sub process_and_store(&@) {
    my $code = shift;
    for (@_) {
        $item = $_;
        &$code();
    }
    undef $item;
}
```

The thing is, `$item` has to be a global scalar for this to work, so `process_and_store` has to update that scalar while looping over the list. You should also `undef $item` at the end of the sub routine to limit any potential side-effects. If I were to write something like this, I'd tuck it away in a module and make it possible to define the iterator variable, so as to limit name conflicts.

Test:

```
my @list = qw(apples pears bananas);
process_and_store { do_something_with($item) } @list;

sub do_something_with {
    my $fruit = shift;
    print "$fruit\n";
}
```

Output:

```
apples
pears
bananas
```

Comment: A lexical variable (`my`) will not be visible in the calling scope unless it's in the same file or scope. It should be `our` and it should be *`local`-ized*.

Comment: @Axeman: Yes, my answer was written before the updates, and now that you've written such a thorough answer I see no reason to update mine.

Answer (score 2):

The `$a` and `$b` variables are special in Perl; they're real global variables and hence exempt from `use strict`, and also used specifically by the `sort()` function.

Most other similar uses in Perl would use the `$_` global for this sort of thing:

```
process_and_store { do_something_with( $_ ) } @list;
```

Which is already handled by the normal `$_` rules. Don't forget to `local`ise `$_`:

```
sub process_and_store(&@)
{
  my $code = shift;
  foreach my $item (@_) {
    local $_ = $item;
    $code->();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to follow your suggestion, but it doesn't quite seem to work when I place the code inside a module (see my updated question). Could you please help with that?